# debug symbols lost during linking...?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2, debug-symbols

I am developing for iOS with XCode 3.2. I compiled my code in debug mode with the `-g` option into a static library. I then linked this library with a bigger static library which has the `main` to create the final executable. This library was built in release mode without any of the debugging support. Now when debugging crashes, I don't see the symbols for my code. Where did they go? Were they stripped by the linker? How can I make the linker retain the debugging information for my library? I have no control over the other library so I won't be able to do anything there.

Comment: There's a build option in Xcode which causes executables to be stripped - it's normally enabled by default for release builds - try turning this off and rebuild.

Comment: I am linking the 2 libraries outside XCode via a build script but I have specified the `-nostrip` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you can build your library, in the Build Settings

- Use the same Debug Information Format for both the library and your code. mixing for example "DWARF with dSYM File " with "DWARF" will not display the symbols
- Build it with any flag related "strip" to NO (or deployment Postprocessing NO)